# Python no activa el archivo, dice que falla la ruta pero el archivo existe

Tags: python

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.18362.778]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Jose>python
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cd desktop
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cd desktop
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 4 +3 +6
13
>>>
```

---

PS C:\Users\Jose\Documents\carpa>jose.py
PS C:\Users\Jose\Documents\carpa> jose.py
jose.py : El término 'jose.py' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa 
ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que
dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.

En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ jose.py
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jose.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Suggestion [3,General]: No se encontró el comando jose.py, pero existe en la ubicación actual. Windows PowerShell no carga comandos de la ubicación actual de forma predeterminada. Si confía en este comando, escriba ".\jose.py". Vea "get-help about_Command_Precedence" para obtener información más detallada.

PS C:\Users\Jose\Documents\carpa>

No se si me expresé bien. Me reconoce la carpeta CARPA, pero no el archivo JOSE.PY. Pero lo abre yyo escribo en él, pero no ejecuta nada: ni print, ni nada. Antes no reconocía la carpeta, ahora sí, pero no el archivo. Pero igual me lo muestra y está abierto, aunque no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` es un comando de CMD, no un builtin o algo por el estilo de Python. Estás en el intérprete interactivo de Python, no en la terminal.

Para cambiar el directorio de trabajo en un script o en intérprete interactivo debes hacer:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("Desktop")
```

No uses `\` para las rutas, ni siquiera en Windows, usa siempre `/`. La `\` indica secuencias de escape (`\n`, `\t`,`\s`, etc), escapar a la propia barra `\\` o usar cadena raw `r"\foo\bar"` puede servir, pero también dan problemas en algunos casos. `/` es universal y más simple:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("C:/Users/Jose/Desktop")
```

Comment: Si tengo `a = "C:/dir01/data"` y `b = "archivo01.txt"` y hago `os.path.join(a, b)` el resultado sera: `C:/dir01/data\\archivo01.txt`. No es muy bonito, pero para efectos prácticos sirve.